Google Places API - invalid place ID
I have an app where I store the Google's place id in my database and then make requests to place details using this id. But, for some of them, I'm getting an error:
The provided Place ID is no longer valid. Please refresh cached Place IDs as per https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/place-id#save-id.

The documentation mentions that when the id becomes obsolete, you can make a place detail request by only requesting the "id" field to trigger the ID refresh SKU. However, this seems to be false. Requesting only the id field still results in the same error. How come? Any ideas how to get it to work?

However, this seems to be false. - Why? Requesting only the id field still results in the same error. - How? Where is your code?

Refreshing a Place ID works when it still exists; otherwise you get NOT_FOUND because the place no longer exists. See Error codes when using place IDs for guidance on how to handle this situation in the future.
